# Any options other than Faye for a real-time activity feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

I would like to integrate a live activity feed in my rails app to show what other Users have recently done, and I'm wondering if there are any options other than running Faye (which seems to add a layer of complexity that I'm not running to introduce, server-wise). I've looked at the public_activity gem, but the solution does not appear to provide data in real-time.

Has anyone implemented a real-time activity feed using other solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at hosted options such as http://pusher.com or others like it.